# How to update SQL with single query and not with php loop?

Tags: php, mysql

These are my tables:

```
tbl_answers => 
  aid     
  qid     
  answer     
  uid     
  dateposted     
  emailnotify
  namedisplay
  status
  isbestanswer 


tbl_questions =>
  qid
  question
  detail
  mcid
  cid
  uid     
  answercount
  dateposted
  status
  showname
  emailnotify
  question_type_id
```

I tried this:

```
UPDATE tbl_questions
JOIN (
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS n 
FROM tbl_questions JOIN tbl_answers ON qid = tbl_questions.qid 
WHERE answercount = "0" 
GROUP BY id
) AS T USING (id)
SET num = n 
WHERE n > 0
```

I woud like to update those question that has got more answers than it's counted in:
tbl_questions =>  answercount

How can I update the rows which have got more questions than it's counted? (Without php loop)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Comment: It would help me more if you could tell me why is not soultion dont work.

Comment: When you say it's not working do you mean that the query won't run, or that the incorrect rows are updated?

Comment: The query don't run, don't update anything.

Comment: You're using a field called `id` that doesn't exist in the table `tbl_questions`, also what is `num` in your query?

Comment: `num` would be `answercount` and... id. Is that valid for that? `tbl_questions.qid` ?

Comment: No, it says: `Column 'qid' in on clause is ambiguous`

Comment: Why are you trying to maintain a parallel count when you can query the database for the count whenever you need it?

Comment: Becouse the database have got more than 1 million rekords and it will be bigger and bigger... Small optimization...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl_questions
  JOIN (
    SELECT tbl_questions.qid, COUNT(*) AS n 
    FROM tbl_questions JOIN tbl_answers ON tbl_answers.qid = tbl_questions.qid  
    GROUP BY qid
  ) AS T USING (qid)
SET answercount = n 
WHERE n > 0'
```