# update row if count(*) > n

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update

my DB has this structure:

```
ID | text | time | valid
```

This is my current code.  I'm trying to find a way to do this as one query.

```
rows = select * from table where ID=x order by time desc;
n=0;
foreach rows{
    if(n > 3){
       update table set valid = -1 where rows[n]; 
    }
    n++
}
```

I'm checking how many rows exist for a given ID.  Then I need to set valid=-1 for all rows where n >3;

Is there a way to do this with one query?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `(id,time)` has a `UNIQUE` constraint, i.e. no two rows have the same `id` and same `time`:

```
UPDATE 
    tableX AS tu
  JOIN
    ( SELECT time
      FROM tableX
      WHERE id = @X                      -- the given ID
      ORDER BY time DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
    ) AS t3
    ON  tu.id = @X                       -- given ID again
    AND tu.time < t3.time 
SET
    tu.valid = -1 ;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
UPDATE table
   SET valid=-1
 WHERE (
         SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM table tt
          WHERE tt.time > table.time
            AND   tt.ID = table.ID
) > 3
```

The subquery counts the rows with the same ID and a later time. This count will be three or less for the three latest rows; the remaining ones would have a greater count, so their `valid` field would be updated.

Comment: I get this error when I try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: @FrancisSnipe Let me try to construct a demo on ideone. What version of MySql are you using?

Answer (score 2):

```
update table 
   set valid = -1
 where id in (select id
                from table 
               where id = GIVEN_ID
            group by id
              having count(1) >3)
```

**Update:** I really like dasblinkenlight's solution because is very neat, but I wanted to try also to do it in my way, a quite verbose one:

```
  update Table1
     set valid = -1
   where (id, time) in (select id, 
                               time
                          from (select id,time
                                  from table1
                                 where id in (select id
                                                from table1
                                            group by id
                                              having count(1) >3)
                                -- and id = GIVEN_ID
                              order by time 
                                 limit 3, 10000000) 
                        t);
```

Also in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af394)

Comment: This would set `valid` to -1 on all rows where the total count is greater than 3. OP's loop keeps the first three rows unchanged, setting `valid` to `-1` on everything after the 4-th row.

Answer (score 0):

to do it for all ids, or only for one if you set a where in the a subquery

```
UPDATE TABLE
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT *
                FROM (
                       SELECT @rn:=if(@prv=id, @rn+1, 1) AS rId,
                              @prv:=id AS id,
                              TABLE.*
                         FROM TABLE
                         JOIN ( SELECT @prv:=0, @rn:=0 ) tmp
                        ORDER BY id, TIMESTAMP 
                     ) a
               WHERE rid > 3
             ) ordered ON ordered.id = TABLE.id
   AND ordered.TIMESTAMP = TABLE.TIMESTAMP
   AND ordered.text = TIMESTAMP.text
   SET VALID = -1
 WHERE rid IS NOT NULL
```