# what is the use of $rows=array()

Tags: php, mysql

**I need to know what to do with $rows=array(). why it is used and how i could use it further. would like to get some suggestions and answers**

```
  <?php


    $dbhost = "localhost"; 
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbdb = "yumyum";


    $connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("connection error");


    mysql_select_db($dbdb) or die("database selection error");


    $id = $_POST['id'];


    $query1=mysql_query("SELECT Quantity,id FROM `yumyum`.`food` where  `food`.`id` LIKE $id");
    $rows = array();

    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {

        $output = $r['Quantity'];


            echo $output;
            $query2=mysql_query("UPDATE food SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 where  `food`.`id` LIKE ".$r["id"]);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: In your coding, it is simply nothing.

Answer (score 6):

In your script it does nothing but initialize the variable `$row` with an `array` type. It would probably be intended to be used in your `while` loop (`$r`):

```
...
$query1=mysql_query("SELECT Quantity,id FROM `yumyum`.`food` where  `food`.`id` LIKE $id");
$r = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
...
```

See [PHP basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a very good practice.

You should also stop using `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: i am new so cant use stack overlow
please give me a gmail

Comment: @user3025252 I don't give out my e-mail. You can join [the Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap-consultancy-) room.

Comment: i do not have enough reputation to tlk on heap

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: my coding can decrement an individual item quantity by 1
can u suggest how to decrement multiple item quantties simultaneously

Comment: @user3025252 [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query) addresses that.

Comment: Thanx but based on my code what should i edit?

Comment: please have a look at it if possible

Comment: @user3025252 please make a new question for it.

Comment: why just tell me how to edit accordingly