# MySQL: How to fill new column of existing table with value based on select from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

My knowledge of SQL trully isn't so great to perform what I want.
I have 2 tables:
One is long data table with many columns, one of them `TypeName`, recently I've added new column to the table `TypeID` (it is empty atm). Like:

```
column1   column2   column3   TypeName    TypeID
------------------------------------------------
...       ...       ...       name1         NULL
...       ...       ...       name2         NULL
...       ...       ...       name1         NULL
...       ...       ...       name3         NULL
...       ...       ...       name1         NULL
...       ...       ...       name4         NULL
...       ...       ...       name5         NULL
```

Second table I call as referenceTable. It has mapping for each possible TypeName to TypeID. Like:

```
TypeID     TypeName
-------------------
0          name1
1          name2
2          name3
etc...
```

I want to fill TypeID in data table based correspondent value in refference table.
What would be the query for that?

EDIT:
Yes I want to remove `TypeName` from data table after I fill `TypeID` columns with correct values.
And ofcourse I'm looking for the query that do this for whole table at once.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried UPDATE ... SELECT ... or read other posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query ?

Comment: I'v eonly tried to come up with UPDATE ... SELECT ... query but my knowlede did allow me only to to it for single row. But how to do such thing for whole table i have no idea. BTW not sure that my UPDATE ... SELECT ... thingy would be corect in first place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to UPDATE not INSERT:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.typeName = t2.typename
SET t1.typeID = t2.typeID
```

But if you are going to have duplicate values on both tables you really should consider have only a foreign key (maybe this typeID) and have the name only in a reference table.

Comment: My intention is to remove TypeName from data table after I populate TypeID with correct values. If so can I do the query you suggested?

Comment: Yes, but make sure you do the query first and remove it after.

Comment: The one above didn't work in sql server. So i ended up with something like below. Just in case someone will need. 

    `UPDATE t1
    SET t1.Column = t2.SomeColumn
    FROM tableToUpdate t1, table2 t2 
    WHERE t2.Id = t1.SomeId `