# Increment File Name Before Extension By 1 in the Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a script which uploads a file and stores the details of the file name in the database.  When a document gets uploaded I want to be able to update the name of the file in the database to be proceeded by an incremental number such as _1, _2, _3 (before the file extension) if the DOCUMENT_ID already exists.  The table structure looks like this:

```
ID   |  DOCUMENT_ID  |  NAME            |  MODIFIED     |   USER_ID
33   |  81           |  document.docx   |  2014-03-21   |   1
34   |  82           |  doc.docx        |  2014-03-21   |   1
35   |  82           |  doc.docx        |  2014-03-21   |   1
36   |  82           |  doc.docx        |  2014-03-21   |   1
```

So in the case above I would want ID 35 NAME to be doc_1.docx and ID 36 NAME to be doc_2.docx.

This is where I have got to so far.  I have retrieved the last file details that have been uploaded:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, DOCUMENT_ID, NAME, MODIFIED 
FROM b_bp_history ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
$ID = $row['ID'];
$documentID = $row['DOCUMENT_ID'];
$documentName = $row['NAME'];
$documentModified = $row['MODIFIED'];
}
```

So this will give me the details I need to see whether the DOCUMENT_ID exists already.  Now I thought it would be best to see if it does exist then by carrying out the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, DOCUMENT_ID 
FROM b_bp_history WHERE DOCUMENT_ID = $documentID";
$result2 = mysqli_query($sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) >0){

/* This is where I need my update */

} else {

/* I don't need an update in here as it will automatically add to the database 
table with no number after it.  Not sure if I should always add the first one 
with a _1 after it so the increment is easy? */

}
```

As you can see from the above I need an update in there that basically checks to see if a number exists after the name and if it does then increment it by one.  On the else statement i.e. if the DOCUMENT_ID doesn't already exist I could add the first one with an _1.docx so that the increment will be easier?

If the DOCUMENT_ID does already exist the update in the first half will need to check the last number before the extension and increment by +1, so if it's _1 then then next will be _2.  Not sure how to do this though either. The end result I want is:

```
ID   |  DOCUMENT_ID  |  NAME              |  MODIFIED     |   USER_ID
33   |  81           |  document.docx     |  2014-03-21   |   1
34   |  82           |  doc.docx          |  2014-03-21   |   1
35   |  82           |  doc_1.docx        |  2014-03-21   |   1
36   |  82           |  doc_2.docx        |  2014-03-21   |   1
```

Comment: I would use ON UPDATE trigger. Listen the change name and update the NAME from the trigger.

Comment: OK, do you have an example of this.  Been scratching my head on how to perform this update and not getting anywhere at present. Thanks

Comment: Does anybody have any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: ...why is this important?  What is it you're doing with the documents that you need to change their filenames?  If I go looking for my file later, I'd be mighty surprised if either 1) the name had changed or 2) I got a different file.  If this is in response to a renaming the OS is doing, you're screwed - you have no guarantee that two interleaved threads won't swap values (or worse).  And what's up with `DOCUMENT_ID`?  How do you know documents are related?  What happens if there is no file extension?  What happens if there's multiple (or multi-part) extensions?

Comment: I'm sorry but what does this have to do with the question? Either answer it or don't.  What we do with documents is our business.  For your information, this information isn't portrayed to the customer, it is saved in a table in the database as a version history.

Comment: This aproach is broken by design. The information stored in columns should be atomic. That means, one column for one thing. In your table you mix up history and name in one column called name. You should consider storing the version number in an extra column like @Richard Pascual suggested. You still can select the data according to your special requirements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Generating a Sequence ID Value in MySQL to Represent a Revision ID Based Naming Convention

> I used `MySQL 5.5.32` to develop and test this solution.  Be sure to review the bottom section of my solution for a few homework assignments for future consideration in your overall design approach.

### Summary of Requirements and Initial Comments

A external script writes to a document history table.  Meta information about a user submitted file is kept in this table, including its user assigned name.  The OP requests a SQL update statement or procedural block of DML operations that will reassign the original document name to one that represents the concept of a discrete `REVISION ID`.

- The original table design contains a independent primary key: `ID`
- An implied business key also exists in the relationship between `DOCUMENT_ID` (a numerical id possibly assigned externally by the script itself) and `MODIFIED` (a DATE typed value representing when the latest revision of a document was submitted/recorded).

> Although other RDBMS systems have useful objects and built-in features such as Oracle's SEQUENCE object and ANALYTICAL FUNCTIONS, There are options available with MySQL's SQL based capabilities.

### Setting up a Working Schema

Below is the DDL script used to build the environment discussed in this solution.  It should match the OP description with an exception (discussed below):

```
 CREATE TABLE document_history 
(
 id int auto_increment primary key, 
 document_id int,
 name varchar(100),
 modified datetime,
 user_id int 
 );

 INSERT INTO document_history (document_id, name, modified,
   user_id)
 VALUES
   (81, 'document.docx', convert('2014-03-21 05:00:00',datetime),1),
   (82, 'doc.docx', convert('2014-03-21 05:30:00',datetime),1),
   (82, 'doc.docx', convert('2014-03-21 05:35:00',datetime),1),
   (82, 'doc.docx', convert('2014-03-21 05:50:00',datetime),1);

 COMMIT;
```

The table `DOCUMENT_HISTORY` was designed with a `DATETIME` typed column for the column called `MODIFIED`.  Entries into the document_history table would otherwise have a high likeliness of returning multiple records for queries organized around the composite business key combination of: `DOCUMENT_ID` and `MODIFIED`.

### How to Provide a Sequenced Revision ID Assignment

A creative solution to SQL based, partitioned row counts is in an older post: [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) by @bobince.

**A SQL query adapted for this task:**

```
 select t0.document_id, t0.modified, count(*) as revision_id
   from document_history as t0
   join document_history as t1
     on t0.document_id = t1.document_id
    and t0.modified >= t1.modified
  group by t0.document_id, t0.modified
  order by t0.document_id asc, t0.modified asc;
```

**The resulting output of this query using the supplied test data:**

```
 | DOCUMENT_ID |                     MODIFIED | REVISION_ID |
 |-------------|------------------------------|-------------|
 |          81 | March, 21 2014 05:00:00+0000 |           1 |
 |          82 | March, 21 2014 05:30:00+0000 |           1 |
 |          82 | March, 21 2014 05:35:00+0000 |           2 |
 |          82 | March, 21 2014 05:50:00+0000 |           3 |
```

Note that the revision id sequence follows the correct order that each version was checked in and the revision sequence properly resets when it is counting a new series of revisions related to a different document id.

> **EDIT:** A good comment from @ThomasKöhne is to consider keeping this `REVISION_ID` as a persistent attribute of your version tracking table.  This could be derived from the assigned file name, but it may be preferred because an index optimization to a single-value column is more likely to work. The Revision ID alone may be useful for other purposes such as creating an accurate `SORT` column for querying a document's history.

### Using MySQL String Manipulation Functions

Revision identification can also benefit from an additional convention: the column name width should be sized to also accommodate for the appended revision id suffix. Some MySQL string operations that will help:

```
 -- Resizing String Values:

 SELECT SUBSTR('EXTRALONGFILENAMEXXX',1,17) FROM DUAL

 | SUBSTR('EXTRALONGFILENAMEXXX',1,17) |
 |-------------------------------------|
 |                   EXTRALONGFILENAME |     


 -- Substituting and Inserting Text Within Existing String Values:

 SELECT REPLACE('THE QUICK <LEAN> FOX','<LEAN>','BROWN') FROM DUAL

 | REPLACE('THE QUICK <LEAN> FOX','<LEAN>','BROWN') |
 |--------------------------------------------------|
 |                              THE QUICK BROWN FOX |


 -- Combining Strings Using Concatenation

 SELECT CONCAT(id, '-', document_id, '-', name) 
   FROM document_history

 | CONCAT(ID, '-', DOCUMENT_ID, '-', NAME) |
 |-----------------------------------------|
 |                      1-81-document.docx |
 |                           2-82-doc.docx | 
 |                           3-82-doc.docx |
 |                           4-82-doc.docx |
```

### Pulling it All Together: Constructing a New File Name Using Revision Notation

Using the previous query from above as a base, inline view (or sub query), this is a next step in generating the new file name for a given revision log record:

**SQL Query With Revised File Name**

```
 select replace(docrec.name, '.', CONCAT('_', rev.revision_id, '.')) as new_name, 
    rev.document_id, rev.modified
   from (
          select t0.document_id, t0.modified, count(*) as revision_id
            from document_history as t0
            join document_history as t1
              on t0.document_id = t1.document_id
             and t0.modified >= t1.modified
           group by t0.document_id, t0.modified
           order by t0.document_id asc, t0.modified asc
       ) as rev
  
  join document_history as docrec
    on docrec.document_id = rev.document_id
   and docrec.modified = rev.modified;
```

**Output With Revised File Name**

```
 |        NEW_NAME | DOCUMENT_ID |                     MODIFIED |
 |-----------------|-------------|------------------------------|
 | document_1.docx |          81 | March, 21 2014 05:00:00+0000 |
 |      doc_1.docx |          82 | March, 21 2014 05:30:00+0000 |
 |      doc_2.docx |          82 | March, 21 2014 05:35:00+0000 |
 |      doc_3.docx |          82 | March, 21 2014 05:50:00+0000 |
```

These (`NEW_NAME`) values are the ones required to update the `DOCUMENT_HISTORY` table.  An inspection of the `MODIFIED` column for `DOCUMENT_ID` = 82 shows that the check-in revisions are numbered in the correct order with respect to this part of the composite business key.

**Finding Un-processed Document Records**

If the file name format is fairly consistent, a SQL `LIKE` operator may be enough to identify the record names which have been already altered. MySQL also offers filtering capabilities through `REGULAR EXPRESSIONS`, which offers more flexibility with parsing through document name values.

What remains is figuring out how to update just a single record or a set of records.  The appropriate place to put the filter criteria would be on the outermost part of the query right after the join between aliased tables:

```
 ...
   and docrec.modified = rev.modified
 WHERE docrec.id = ??? ;
```

There are other places where you can optimize for faster response times, such as within the internal sub query that derives the revision id value... the more you know about the specific set of records that you are interested in, you can segment the beginning SQL statements to look only at what is of interest.

### Homework: Some Closing Comments on the Solution

This stuff is purely optional and they represent some side thoughts that came to mind on aspects of design and usability while writing this up.

**Two-Step or One-Step?**

With the current design, there are two discrete operations per record: `INSERT` by a script and then `UPDATE` of the value via a SQL DML call.  It may be annoying to have to remember two SQL commands.  Consider building a second table built for insert only operations.

- Use the second table (`DOCUMENT_LIST`) to hold nearly identical information, except possibly two columns:

  1. `BASE_FILE_NAME` (i.e., doc.docx or document.docx) which may apply for multiple HISTORY_ID values.
  2. `FILE_NAME` (i.e., doc_1.docx, doc_2.docx, etc.) which will be unique for each record.
- Set a database `TRIGGER` on the source table: `DOCUMENT_HISTORY` and put the SQL query we've developed inside of it.  This will automatically populate the correct revision file name at roughly the same moment after the script fills the history table.

> **WHY BOTHER?** This suggestion mainly fits under the category of `SCALABILITY` of your database design.  The assignment of a revision name is still a two step process, but the second step is now handled automatically within the database, whereas you'd have to remember to include it everywhere you invoked a DML operation on top of the history table.

**Managing Aliases**

I didn't see it anywhere, but I assume that the `USER` initially assigns some name to the file being tracked.  In the end, it appears that it may not matter as it is an internally tracked thing that the end user of the system would never see.

> For your information, this information isn't portrayed to the customer, it is saved in a table in the database as a version history...

Reading the history of a given document would be easier if the "base" name was kept the same once it has been given:

[image: Varying File Names]

In the data sample above, unless the `DOCUMENT_ID` is known, it may not be clear that all the file names listed are related.  This may not necessarily be a problem, but it is a good practice from a semantic point of view to separate user assigned file names as `ALIASES` that can be changed and assigned at will at any time.

Consider setting up a separate table for tracking the "User-Friendly" name given by the end user, and associating it with the document id it is supposed to represent. A user may make hundreds or thousands of rename requests... while the back end file system uses a simpler, more consistent naming approach.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar trouble recently, but I'm using MSSQL and I don't no MySQL syntax, so here is a T-SQL code. Hope, it will help you!

```
declare 
    @id int,
    @document_id int,
    @document_name varchar(255),
    @append_name int,
    @name varchar(255),
    @extension varchar(10)

set @append_name = 1

select top 1
    @id = ID,
    @document_id = DOCUMENT_ID,
    @document_name = NAME
from
    b_bp_history

while exists (
    select *
    from b_bp_history
    where 
        NAME = @document_name and
        DOCUMENT_ID = @document_id and
        ID <> @id)
begin
    set @name = ''
    set @extension = ''

    declare @dot_index int -- index of dot-symbol in document name
    set @dot_index = charindex('.', reverse(@document_name))

    if (@dot_index > 0)
    begin       
        set @name = substring(@document_name, 0, len(@document_name) - @dot_index + 1)
        set @extension = substring(@document_name, len(@document_name) - @dot_index + 2, len(@document_name) - len(@name))
    end
    else
        set @name = @document_name

    if (@append_name > 1) -- if not first try to rename file
    begin
        if (right(@name, len(cast(@append_name - 1 as varchar)) + 1)) = '_' + cast(@append_name - 1 as varchar)
        begin
            set @name = substring(@name, 0, len(@name) - (len(cast(@append_name - 1 as varchar))))
        end
    end

    set @name = @name + '_' + cast(@append_name as varchar)

    if (len(@extension) > 0)
        set @document_name = @name + '.' + @extension
    else
        set @document_name = @name


    set @append_name = @append_name + 1
end

update b_bp_history
set NAME = @document_name
where ID = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **Working UPDATE QUERY**

```
UPDATE document_history
INNER JOIN (SELECT dh.id, IF(rev.revision_id = 0, dh.name,REPLACE(dh.name, '.', CONCAT('_', rev.revision_id, '.'))) AS new_name, 
rev.document_id, rev.modified
FROM (
SELECT t0.document_id, t0.modified, count(*) - 1 AS revision_id
FROM document_history as t0
JOIN document_history as t1
ON t0.document_id = t1.document_id
AND t0.modified >= t1.modified
GROUP BY t0.document_id, t0.modified
ORDER BY t0.document_id ASC, t0.modified ASC) AS rev
JOIN document_history dh
ON dh.document_id = rev.document_id
AND dh.modified = rev.modified) update_record
ON document_history.id = update_record.id
SET document_history.name = update_record.new_name;
```

You can see the SQL Fiddle at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b3cda/1

I used the information available on this page on `UPDATE` to assemble my query:

[MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query)

Used the page below for generating a `Revision ID`:

[ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Also used the schema provided by Richard Pascual in his elaborate answer.

Hope this query helps you to name your document as you wish.