# How to update one table from another table?

Tags: mysql

I want to update rows from one table to another, both have same structure and i use this query

```
UPDATE bh_master_ritesh_stock AS st
SET st.tag_uid = apprv.tag_uid ,st.stk_id = apprv.stk_id
FROM bh_stock_approval AS apprv
WHERE st.stock_id = apprv.stock_id
```

but it gives me this error,

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'FROM bh_stock_approval as apprv WHERE st.stock_id = apprv.stock_id' at line 3
```

where is my mistake? or am I using wrong query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
UPDATE bh_master_ritesh_stock AS st,bh_stock_approval AS apprv
SET st.tag_uid = apprv.tag_uid ,st.stk_id = apprv.stk_id 
WHERE st.stock_id = apprv.stock_id
```

because `UPDATE` cant use `From` clause

Comment: the question is where the mistake.. if the question is how to effectively the query is should rather use a join :)

Answer (score 1):

You syntax is simply wrong, "FROM" is unexpected:

```
UPDATE bh_master_ritesh_stock AS st,bh_stock_approval AS apprv
SET st.tag_uid = apprv.tag_uid ,st.stk_id = apprv.stk_id 
WHERE st.stock_id = apprv.stock_id
```

For other examples that involves more tables, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UPDATE bh_master_ritesh_stock st
INNER JOIN bh_stock_approval apprv on
  st.stock_id = apprv.stock_id
SET 
  st.tag_uid = apprv.tag_uid ,st.stk_id = apprv.stk_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE bh_master_ritesh_stock A
SET A.tag_uid, A.stk_id =( select B.tag_uid, B.stk_id
FROM bh_stock_approval B WHERE A.stock_id = B.stock_id)
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT '1' FROM bh_stock_approval B1 WHERE A.stock_id =B1.stock_id)
```