# Update table data using foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables structure like below

Table1

```
Serial  |   Src            | Albumid(primarykey)  
________|__________________|________
   1    |   /root/wewe.jpg |   20
   2    |   /root/wewe.jpg |   21
   3    |   /root/wewe.jpg |   21
   4    |   /root/wewe.jpg |   23
   5    |   /root/wewe.jpg |   18
```

Table2

```
Albumid |  Albumname       | AlbumCover  //albumid is secondary key ref. to first table
________|__________________|________
   20   |   AAA            |   null
   21   |   bbb            |   null
   31   |   vcc            |   null
   42   |   ddd            |   null
   18   |   eee            |   null
```

I followed this [POST](http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/) two update my `Albumcover` in `Table2` using `Serial no.` of first table..

```
create proc AddCover @Serial int
as
Begin
update Table1 set albumcover='somthing' where table1.serial = @Serial
end
```

Can i do like this using foregin key constraint??

Comment: looks a like you are you are confused in fields of Table1 and Table2 , in your update statement. As Table1 does not have albumcover...!!!

Comment: Please explain more clearly...!!!

Comment: Yea...im getting confused by seeing in the post,,Have u seen the post i posted in question...Look at the "Cascading in Action" section...

Comment: Write single statement what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: to update the album cover in 2nd table by using the Serialno. in 1St table...this is what i want to achive...

Comment: But there is no relation between table1 SerialNo and table2 columns..!!

Comment: Still cant understand it, from data shown here it looks like your table2 Albumid is PK and table1 Albumid is FK ref to Table2... ;(

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do the update on Table2.  To tell it to have a condition based on values from table1, check this post for examples:

[MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query)