# Updating rows with value of another column in a different table

Tags: mysql

There are two same structured tables i.e. One & Two. I want to update one column with values of another table's same column.
Have a look at this:

**Table One**

```
id  name  value
1   a     11
2   b     12
3   c     13
```

**Table Two**

```
id  name  value
1   c     11
2   d     12
3   e     13
```

I want to update `one.name` with the values of `two.name`. How do I do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` in the `UPDATE` to relate the two tables.

```
UPDATE One
JOIN Two ON One.value = Two.value
SET One.name = Two.name
```

If you need to use `LIMIT`, you have to use a subquery:

```
UPDATE One
JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM Two
      LIMIT 100) AS Two
ON One.value = Two.value
SET One.name = Two.name
```

Comment: Yeah I got that but I can't use limit with this query. Unless I test it on a couple of rows, I can't go ahead & update the whole table. Is there any way I can put limit in this?

Comment: @ShanilSoni Its not very nice to change the requirements on the fly.

Comment: I'm sorry, requirement is to update the whole table, just wanted to test on a couple of rows. Requirement remains the same