# Insert a new record in MySQL table at start

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and learning it to my own. Actually I want to copy a column from a table into my existing table column! suppose that my existing table is:

[image]

where pid values are inserted by default!
now i want to copy a column from another table using:

```
  INSERT INTO exist_tab(FirstLevel) SELECT some_col FROM another_table;
```

so that the values should come inside FirstLevel Column.
but the problem is that the copies values come below the pid values in FirstLevel Column as:

[image]

see that the firstlevel comes below! what is wrong with it? I need the "H" value against 19 but i dont want to use wild cards just want to copy the new data against old column data
thanks
I am new to this kind a work please can somebody give me any idea how to do it please! 
thanks in advance

Comment: So yoiu want to remove the old data ?

Comment: Use an UPDATE not an INSERT. You want to change an existing row and not create a new one.

Comment: if using update how can i copy the column values? i mean how can i use insert into and update?

Comment: It's select and update not insert into and update.

Comment: i know it but how can i update in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `INSERT` statement here. INSERT will create a new record in the table. You have to use `UPDATE` for updating a particular column in the existing table like this:

```
UPDATE exist_tab 
SET FirstLevel = (SELECT some_col FROM another_table)
```

If you want any conditional update then you can use `JOIN` like this:

```
UPDATE exist_tab a
LEFT JOIN another_table b ON
a.pid = b.id
SET FirstLevel = a.some_col;
```

Comment: your query has an error at after "from" clause test it yourself

Comment: I have updated my answer. The error was bcoz that was for `MS SQL` not `Mysql`

Answer (score 0):

> INSERT and UPDATE is different Command to Perform Different Task.
>
> INSERT :Insert New Record into the table
>
> Update:Update Existing Record in table If Exist.

*NOT SURE ABOUT IT:(i'm Not Familiar With MYSQL)*

```
Update a set 
a.FirstLevel=b.some_col
from 
exist_tab a join another_table b on a.Id=b.Id
```

Or You can Try :

```
update exist_tab a set a.FirstLevel=
(select top 1 some_col from another_table where Id=a.Id)
```

EDIT2:

```
update exist_tab a set a.FirstLevel=
    (select top 1 some_col from another_table)
```

You Can Find [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query).

Comment: i dont have to use ids or any kind of wild card

Comment: answer updated : Try `update exist_tab a set a.FirstLevel=
(select top 1 some_col from another_table )` this. @JavaNerd

Comment: for your kindness its mssql server syntax!

Comment: it'll update all record in your table. trust me, just give it a try.
@JavaNerd