# Select and update the same row using while loop

Tags: php, oop, join, mysqli

There is a looping query (while loop) to select 2 column values from a table, then the code sums the 2 values,  what I need is to update another column with the summed value>
Here is the code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('select value1, value2, valuse3  from  eg.table limit ? ');
$stmt->bind_param('i',$limit);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($value1, $value2,$value3);
$arr = array();
while($stmt->fetch()) {
$row = array();
array_push($arr, $row);
$newvalue=($value1+$value2);

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE eg.table SET eg.column=? WHERE  eg2.column=?");
$stmt1->bind_param('ii',$newvalue , $value3);
$stmt1->execute();
}
```

When I used this queries I got this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\so\new\socialrank.php on line 13

If you have another solution to achieve the job using Mysqli it's okay.
Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's usually bad practice to execute SQL queries inside loops. It would be better to build a bulk query in the loop and execute it once afterward.

Comment: Apparently your statement could not be prepared and the operation returned false (hence boolean). Apart from that, I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. I assume valuse is a typo for value? And where did table eg2 in the WHERE clause come from?

Comment: @StuartWagner I agree with you, but I don't know how can I do that (I mean the bulk query), I thought about using JOIN but I even didn't imagine how can I write it to select and update after making a calculating process.

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni You know, when I perform each query alone both of them work! My mind now is 0, no solutions come to it :) so if you have a suggested solution, please post it.

Comment: As I said, I don't understand what you're trying to do. So until you explain, I won't have a solution.

Comment: Anyways, I got the solution, and I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. This query do the same thing I was looking for:

```
$sql = ("UPDATE eg.table AS c1, eg.table AS c2 
SET c1.eg.column = (c2.value1 + c2.value2)
WHERE c2.eg2.column = c1.eg2.column
");
```

Note: this solution is inspired by @CakePHP [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query)