# MySql: count+1 in a SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

How i put an update in a SELECT-query at once. 
I wish to count a field from the SELECTed row.

```
SELECT * FROM `_server` order by hits asc LIMIT 1 (update `_server` set `hits`=hits+1)
```

Comment: You don't - they're two separate statements.

Comment: Not sure what you mean dazzafact. Is the goal of selecting the hits to display it to the user first? If so, @Siyual is right. Otherwise, you might be implying something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Comment: Which rows you want to update? There is no `WHERE` condition in your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order by` and `limit` in `update`:

```
update `_server`
    set hits = hits + 1
    order by hits asc
    limit 1;
```

Comment: i cant get the query "while ($row = $res->fetch_row())"

Comment: I have no idea what your comment is supposed to convey.  For instance, your question says nothing about application code.