# Flag the row with the max value in field B based on name field in Field A

Tags: mysql, max

I am able to find the row with the maximum value for a Value field in an given set of records with the same name using

```
Select Name, Max(Value) from table group by Name, Value
```

which returns to me the record with the highest value but I am looking to turn this into an update so I can

- Flag the record with the highest value in a `IsMaxValue`
- For each record in the Name, Value group store the highest value found in a 'MaxValue' field

Simple select version is here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccd32/5

with fields ready for updates as per above if it is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query)

Comment: Is this what you want? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3523/1

Comment: @jpw the output is yes though I can't see how yours differs. Ah my bad I need to learn to use the scroll bar. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkH the update query is in the left pane of the fiddle. If this gives the result you want I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Don't store derived data

Comment: @MarkH So, did my proposed solution work for you? If so, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this statement is what you might be looking for:

```
update maxvalues
join (
  Select Color, Max(`Value`) max_value 
  from MaxValues 
  group by Color
) a on maxvalues.color = a.color and value = a.max_value
set ismaxrecord = '1', maxrecordid = a.max_value;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3523/1)

Given your sample data the table would look like below after the update:

```
|  Color | Value | IsMaxRecord | MaxRecordID |
|--------|-------|-------------|-------------|
| Orange |     1 |             |           0 |
| Orange |     2 |             |           0 |
| Orange |     3 |           1 |           3 |
|  Black |    30 |           1 |          30 |
|  Black |    20 |             |           0 |
|  Black |    10 |             |           0 |
```