# Mixing 3 sql queries in 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables as follows

Table1

```
Id Name
1   abcd
2   bcd
3   dabc
```

Table2

```
Id2 Name2
2   xyz
3   def
4   mno
```

Table3

```
Id  Id2  Value
1    4    1
2    3    1
3    4    1
```

Now,

From table1 : I have to select all Id where Name is %abc%
From table2: I have to select Id2 where Name2 is "mno"
From Table3: I have to change value to 0 from 1 where Id's value are from Table1 and Id2 is from Table2.

Table 1:

```
select Id from Table1 where Name like '%abc%'
```

Table2 :

```
select Id2 from Table2 where Name2 = "mno"
```

Table 3:

```
update Table3 set Value = 0 where Id in() and Id2=
```

But, I dont know how to make it 1 single query. Can anyone please guide me up ?

Comment: You should look into join queries"http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html"

Comment: Nice Visual aid on joins here: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 2):

Refer to: [prior stack article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query)

You've not explained how T1 relates to T2, So I have assumed a cross join.

Whenever you have a record in T1 with name like '%abc%' (1,3) in your data..
and whenever you have a record in T2 with a name equal to 'mno' 4 then you want the value in table 3 to be 0

so the select we generate should produce
1,4
3,4

and when we inner join this back to table 3 it only selects

```
Id  Id2  Value
1    4    1
3    4    1
```

Now we generate an update based on this select as outlined in the link provided above...

```
UPDATE table3 
INNER JOIN (
  SSELECT t1.ID t1ID, t2.id t2ID
  FROM table1 t1
  CROSS JOIN table2
  WHERE t1.name like '%abc%'
    and t2.name like = 'mno') B
 on B.t1ID = t3.Id 
and B.t2ID = T3.ID2
SET value = 0
```

Giving us a result of

```
Id  Id2  Value
1    4    0
2    3    1
3    4    0

if we select * from table3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update t3
set t3.Value = 0
from Table3 t3
inner join Table1 t1
  on t3.Id = t1.Id
inner join Table2 t2
  on t3.Id2 = t2.Id2
where t1.Name like '%abc%' and t2.Name2 = 'mno'
```

OR

```
update Table3
set value = 0
where Id in (select Id from Table1 where Name like '%abc%')
and Id2 in (select Id2 from Table2 where Name2 = 'mno')
```

Comment: Notice, try to avoid using IN subqueries as possible and use EXISTS instead.
Ref: http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/
Thank you

Comment: not really. read about subquery optimization by optimizer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

You should think about UPDATE ... WHERE EXISTS as follows:

```
update Table3 set Value = 0 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 where Name LIKE '%abc%' AND  Table1.Id=Table3.Id )
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 where Name2 = "mno" AND Table2.Id2=Table3.Id2)
```