# How to run a sql query inside a while of another sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

Hi my code as follow:-

```
$sql="SELECT student_id,DA1,DA2,DA3,DA4,DA5,DA6,HA1,HA2,HA3,HA4,HA5,HA6 from table";
$results = $result->query($sql);
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{
   $id = $row['student_id'];
   $marks1 = $row['DA1'] + $row['HA1']/2 ;
   $marks2 = $row['DA2'] + $row['HA2']/2 ;
   $marks3 = $row['DA3'] + $row['HA3']/2 ;
   $marks4 = $row['DA4'] + $row['HA4']/2 ;
   $marks5 = $row['DA5'] + $row['HA5']/2 ;
   $marks6 = $row['DA6'] + $row['HA6']/2 ;

   $i = 1;
   while($i <= 6)
   {
      $sql = "SELECT `grade`,`point` FROM `grades` where  ${'marks' . $i} BETWEEN min and max";
      $results = $result->query($sql);
      $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
      ${'grade' . $i} = $row['grade'];
      ${'point' . $i} = $row['point'];
      $i++;
    }  

    $totalcredit = 20;
    $sgpa= ($point1*$c1 + $point2*$c2 + $point3*$c3 + $point4*$c4 + $point5*$c5 + $point6*$c6) / $totalcredit ;

    $sql = "UPDATE table SET `G1` = '$grade1', `G2` = '$grade2' ,`G3` ='$grade3',`G4` = '$grade4',`G5` = '$grade5',`G6` = '$grade6', `SGPA` = '$sgpa' WHERE student_id = '$id'";
    $result->query($sql);
 }
```

In this code i am trying to calculate grade and sgpa of a class. In the first query selecting all the details and calulating total marks in six subjects. In the second query i am storing the grade and point in variables with respect to the marks and then calculating the sgpa. Then the update query is performed to store the details in database.

**The table consist of 100 rows. The code is working for the first row but does not work for another rows and returns empty values. I am recursively trying to calculate and update the table with data of all students. I would be highly grateful if anybody can help in running the code for all the rows.**

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Comment: change $results to $results2 inside the sql loop.  Looks like you are overriding one for the other.

Comment: Your inner WHILE is overwriting the contents of your variable $results

Comment: where are you values `$c1` - `$c6` coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the inner while loop like this:-

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 6)
{
  $sql = "SELECT `grade`,`point` FROM `grades` where  ${'marks' . $i} BETWEEN min and max";
  $results2 = $result->query($sql);
  $row = $results2->fetch_assoc();
  ${'grade' . $i} = $row['grade'];
  ${'point' . $i} = $row['point'];
  $i++;
}
```

In your code $results is getting overrided so changing it to $results2 in inner loop will solve your problem.

Comment: @cmorrissey $result does not need to be changed as it as database connection object.

Comment: Thank you very much @Kushal Srivastava changing $results solved the problem.