# How to check given value is greater than or equal to in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

If a player has earned certain points ,based on the points there are some levels,now if I have the total points of player I want to update his/her level by checking into the table whether the player has exceeded the minimum score limit to attain the next level ?

```
level   desc      points
 1      level 1    200
 2      level 2    400
 3      level 3    600
```

player current points are 350 as soon as he reaches 400 his level should be updated to 2

```
playerid    playername  level
  1            abc        1
  2            xyz        3
```

Comment: perhaps write a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update table_name
set level =case when points <350 then 1
                when points >= 350 then 2 
                else 3  
           end
```

Comment: if I pass points as a parameter then it will stop at 2
even if there are additional levels available because when will evaluate to true

when 500 <350 then 1
                when 500 >= 350 then 2 
               when 500 >=400 then 3
                else 4

Comment: @swanandkeskar if you have more that these level than you can create dynamic case statement that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table named *players* with fields **id** and **points** and a table named *levels* with fields **level** and **points** than the following query will work

```
 SELECT players.*,max(levels.level) AS level 
 FROM players 
 LEFT JOIN levels ON players.points >= levels.points 
 GROUP BY players.id
```

Comment: Updating from a select is covered in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query