# SQL syntax error : 'FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B ON table_A.name = table_B.name' at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got an error saying that" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B ON table_A.name = table_B.name' at line 1 "

The sql query is :

```
$sql="UPDATE table_A SET table_A.quantity = table_A.quantity -  
table_B.quantity FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B ON table_A.name = table_B.name 
WHERE table_B.status = 'APPROVED'";
```

Please help me out of this error. Thank you.

Comment: INNER should be inner join?

Comment: You wrote `INNER` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: uppsss sorry. it's a typo. I'm using INNER JOIN

Comment: You can't do an `UPDATE` like that in `MySQL` - see this question for the correct syntax:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Comment: Wait, what... I don't think that's legal in `MySql`

Answer (score 0):

"INNER" should be "INNER JOIN"

I think you also have to take out "table_A" from "SET quantity"

```
 $sql="UPDATE table_A SET quantity = table_A.quantity -  
    table_B.quantity FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B ON table_A.name = table_B.name 
    WHERE table_B.status = 'APPROVED'";
```

Comment: but, I've got this : Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error.

Correct syntaxs for `UPDATE` with `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE T1,T2
[INNER JOIN | LEFT JOIN] T1 ON T1.C1 = T2. C1
SET T1.C2 = T2.C2, 
    T2.C3 = expr
WHERE condition
```

Query:

```
$sql="UPDATE table_A 
INNER JOIN table_B ON table_A.name = table_B.name 
SET table_A.quantity = table_A.quantity - table_B.quantity
WHERE table_B.status = 'APPROVED'";
```

Comment: but, I've got this : Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);

Comment: You must use mysql_affected_rows().