# MySQL update from select

Tags: php, mysql

Having trouble with this query:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.custom_id=(SELECT t2.custom_id 
FROM table2 t2 WHERE LOWER(t1.first_name)=LOWER(t2.first_name) 
AND LOWER(t1.last_name)=LOWER(t2.last_name) 
AND (t2.zip1 LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.zip,'%') 
OR t2.zip2 LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.zip,'%')) LIMIT 1)
```

I triple-checked that php variables match the field names. When I split it into multiple queries update works fine.

Comment: variable is coming from where? / errors are what? is it executed? not enough code/information here IMHO and the schemas

Comment: and why are you ticking `\`` the variables?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: table1 is created from CSV and these variables are created from field names. Then I need to run this update. It's executed and no errors.

Comment: well I for one fail to see how you are checking for (possible) errors and what the csv is.

Comment: Backticks because field names might have spaces.

Comment: Is `$zip` a field name?

Comment: question's too unclear for me. you'll have to wait for someone else then because I can't go and setup a csv/tables for this. You'll need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: $zip is a field name.

Comment: Is that the proper way of evaluating the variables? (I understand you want to return the column names in place) I assume   that when you test in separate requests you're not capable of reproducing this situation, but that you directly use the column names...

Comment: You're testing a column against a column name?

Comment: Scratch the CSV and variables. I'll modify the query.

Comment: run an echo/var_dump and you'll see what's going through your query (or not).

Comment: *"When I split it into multiple queries update works fine."* - Then my "guess" is; you're trying to run multiple queries with php but didn't use `mysqli_multi_query()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php - If it works in phpmyadmin but not in php (as tagged) then something failed you; check for errors. That's the best I can add to all this, and the db schemas are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You could have tried searching [StackOIverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query) for an answer first, but in your case something like this should work:

```
 UPDATE table1 t1
 join table2 t2 on
 LOWER (t1.first_name) = LOWER (t2.first_name)
        AND LOWER (t1.last_name) = LOWER (t2.last_name)
         AND (   t2.zip1 LIKE CONCAT ('%', t1.zip, '%')
             OR t2.zip2 LIKE CONCAT ('%', t1.zip, '%')) LIMIT 1)
 SET custom_id = t2.custom_id
```