# Trying to use DATEADD and getting function does not exist error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the table `TableName` which contains approximately 5,000 rows.  It consists of a `product_id` and a `ScheduleTime`.

What I want to do with this table is replace each value of `ScheduleTime`, regardless of whatever it might currently be.  Each record's new value of `ScheduleTime` should be set to the nominee value of `20` minutes after the previous record's, with the following exception.  If a nominee `ScheduleTime` occurs after `22:30:00` or before `05:00:00` (i.e. it is too late or too early), then it should be set to the next available datetime.

I should be able to specify what the first new value of `ScheduleTime` will be.

This is the query that I am using at the moment...

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET ScheduleTime = DATEADD( MI, ScheduleTime, 20 ) 
WHERE CAST( ScheduleTime AS TIME ) >= '22:30:00' 
   OR CAST( ScheduleTime AS TIME ) < '05:00:00';
```

But it is producing this error message...

```
#1305 - FUNCTION DatabaseName.DATEADD does not exist
```

This query can be used to create the table that I have...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableName
(
    product_id VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    ScheduleTime DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am populating the above table using the following sample data...

```
INSERT INTO TableName ( product_id,
                        ScheduleTime )
VALUES ( '01', '2017-05-07 22:00:59' ),
       ( '02', '2017-05-07 09:09:59' ),
       ( '03', '2017-05-07 09:59:59' ),
       ( '04', '2017-05-07 09:49:59' ),
       ( '05', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '06', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '07', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '08', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '09', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '10', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '11', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '12', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '13', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '14', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '15', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '16', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '17', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '18', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '19', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '20', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' );
```

Comment: Try `DATE_ADD( ScheduleTime, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE )` (note the `_`).  Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `MI`?

Comment: @toonice MI was standing  for minutes, when I use `UPDATE Database 
SET ScheduleTime = DATE_ADD(ScheduleTime, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) 
where CAST(ScheduleTime as time) < '22:30:00' 
   or CAST(ScheduleTime as time) >= '05:00:00'; `It does not give me error but it also does not change anything in the table

Comment: Likely to do with the `WHERE` statement.  I need to check a couple of things.  Won't be long.

Comment: Have you tried my Answer?

Comment: @toonice yes but still data is the same, my date format in the entire column is 2017-05-07 20:49:48  in all rows

Comment: Do you mean that all of your time values *are* `20:49:38` or just of that format?  Also, what type is the field `ScheduleTime`?

Comment: all values are the same which is "2017-05-07 20:49:48" and now I need to change those all to start from "2017-05-07 20:49:48" and add 20 mins interval with the where clause attached. scheduletime is the column's name in the table which needs to be updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143641/discussion-between-toonice-and-schwann).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SET @workingScheduleTime := ( SELECT DATE_ADD( '2017-05-06 22:00:59', INTERVAL -20 MINUTE ) );
UPDATE TableName
JOIN ( SELECT product_id,
              CASE
                  WHEN TIME( DATE_ADD( @workingScheduleTime, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE ) ) NOT BETWEEN '05:00:01' and '22:29:59' THEN
                      @workingScheduleTime := DATE_ADD( TIMESTAMP( DATE( @workingScheduleTime ), '05:00:01' ), INTERVAL 1 DAY )
                  ELSE
                      @workingScheduleTime := DATE_ADD( @workingScheduleTime, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE )
              END AS ScheduleTime
       FROM TableName
     ) AS redatedList ON TableName.product_id = redatedList.product_id
SET TableName.ScheduleTime = redatedList.ScheduleTime;
```

This solution by works by looping through each record and adding `20` `minutes` to the value given to the previous record's `ScheduleTime` field.  It also allows the initial value of `ScheduleTime` to be specified.  Thus we will need to start with a working value of `ScheduleTime` that is `20` `minutes` *before* our initial value so that the first iteration of the loop will return our initial value.  Thus my solution starts with the statement...

```
SET @workingScheduleTime := ( SELECT DATE_ADD( '2017-05-06 22:00:59', INTERVAL -20 MINUTE ) );
```

With our working value thus initialised I have implemented an `UPDATE` of the table `TableName` using a `SELECT` statement based upon `Eric`'s  solution found at [MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query).  The statement follows...

```
UPDATE TableName
JOIN ( SELECT product_id,
              CASE
                  WHEN TIME( DATE_ADD( @workingScheduleTime, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE ) ) NOT BETWEEN '05:00:01' and '22:29:59' THEN
                      @workingScheduleTime := DATE_ADD( TIMESTAMP( DATE( @workingScheduleTime ), '05:00:01' ), INTERVAL 1 DAY )
                  ELSE
                      @workingScheduleTime := DATE_ADD( @workingScheduleTime, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE )
              END AS ScheduleTime
       FROM TableName
     ) AS redatedList ON TableName.product_id = redatedList.product_id
SET TableName.ScheduleTime = redatedList.ScheduleTime;
```

This statement starts by performing an `INNER JOIN` between one instance of `TableName` to the results of the following subquery based on their shared value of `product_id`...

```
SELECT product_id,
       CASE
           WHEN TIME( DATE_ADD( @workingScheduleTime, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE ) ) NOT BETWEEN '05:00:01' and '22:29:59' THEN
               @workingScheduleTime := DATE_ADD( TIMESTAMP( DATE( @workingScheduleTime ), '05:00:01' ), INTERVAL 1 DAY )
           ELSE
               @workingScheduleTime := DATE_ADD( @workingScheduleTime, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE )
           END AS ScheduleTime
FROM TableName
```

This subquery selects the value of `product_id` for each record in `TableName` and then checks if the next value of the working value will occur within a timeframe prohibited by the Questioner as being too late / too early.  If it does then the next acceptable time (`05:00:01` on the next day) is chosen by the `CASE` statement.  If the nominee value falls within the acceptable timeframe then it is chosen by the `CASE` statement.  The working value is updated

The value chosen by the `CASE` statement is then chosen as the subquery's new value of `ScheduleTime`.

As mentioned above the results of the subquery are then joined to `TableName` in such way that each existing record of `TableName` effectively has it's new value appended to it.  The `SET` statement uses this newly established relationship to change each existing value of `ScheduleTime` to its corresponding new value.

This answer was tested against a dataset created using the `CREATE` statement from the Question and populated using the following script...

```
INSERT INTO TableName ( product_id,
                        ScheduleTime )
VALUES ( '01', '2017-05-07 22:00:59' ),
       ( '02', '2017-05-07 09:09:59' ),
       ( '03', '2017-05-07 09:59:59' ),
       ( '04', '2017-05-07 09:49:59' ),
       ( '05', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '06', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '07', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '08', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '09', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '10', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '11', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '12', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '13', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '14', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '15', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '16', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '17', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '18', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '19', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' ),
       ( '20', '2017-05-07 23:09:59' );
```

The results of my code have been confirmed as appropriate by the Questioner.

*Further Reading*

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between (on MySQL's `BETWEEN` and `NOT BETWEEN` operators)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date (on MySQL's `DATE()` function)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add (on MySQL's `DATE_ADD()` function)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html (on MySQL's `SET` statement)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time (on MySQL's `TIME()` function)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp (on MySQL's `TIMESTAMP()` function)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html (on MySQL's `UPDATE` statement)

Comment: Thank you for spending hours of time working to fix this issue for me. I cannot say how much I appreciate this. The code works flawlessly and it even gives option to define a custom start time and date.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help.  I shall have an explanation added shortly.

Comment: Explanation added.  Also, an error was spotted.  Before, when it found that a nominee `ScehduleTime` value within the prohibited timeframe it set the time component to `05:00:01` and the date component to the *same* day, rather than the *next* day as it should have.  This error has now been corrected in my Answer.  My apologies if this has caused any inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending even more time to fix the issue that I did not even notice. God Bless you.