# MySQL update the same table based on results of a select

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table called `downloads` which has records of files which have been downloaded from various URL's. There is a column `downloads.created` which is a `DATETIME` and a column `downloads.master` which is a boolean field to say which record is the master copy.

The following query successfully gets the records which have the most recent date:

```
SELECT t1.master
FROM downloads t1
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
             FROM downloads t2
             WHERE t2.url_id = t1.url_id            
             ORDER BY t2.created DESC
             LIMIT 1)
```

I want to update these records by setting `master` to `1`.

Both the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` I want to perform apply to the **same table**, `downloads`

I have tried the following [MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query) :

```
UPDATE downloads 
(
    SELECT t1.master
    FROM downloads t1
    WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
             FROM downloads t2
             WHERE t2.url_id = t1.url_id            
             ORDER BY t2.created DESC
             LIMIT 1)
 )
 SET master = 1
```

But this gives an error:

`Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(
SELECT t1.master
FROM downloads t1
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
               ' at line 2`

Other solutions I tried on the above link updated the entire table, where as I'm just trying to update the records retrieved from the working `SELECT` I have. Please can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: read about `update ... join`

Comment: whats the condition for update?

Comment: @PriyeshKumar The condition is to `SET master = 1` but I only want to do that for the records that are returned from the `SELECT` statement, not the entire table.

Comment: The update statement applies to a table, not to the results of a select. Furthermore, you cannot select from a table that is being updated, so use joins as @Jens has suggested.

Comment: update t1.master SET t1.master = 1 where WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
             FROM downloads t2
             WHERE t2.url_id = t1.url_id            
             ORDER BY t2.created DESC
             LIMIT 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use join and update together to do something like this. Try

```
  UPDATE downloads d
  JOIN (SELECT t1.id FROM downloads t1 
        WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
                       FROM downloads t2
                       WHERE t2.url_id = t1.url_id            
                       ORDER BY t2.created DESC LIMIT 1
                       ) 
        ) a on d.id = a.id  SET d.`master` = 1
```

That should work, and maybe you could optimize little bit more how you extract most recent records

Answer (score 2):

use **join**

```
update t1 SET t1.master = 1  from downloads as  t1 
join downloads as  t2 
on t2.url_id = t1.url_id 
ORDER BY t2.created DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Gives an error `Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
FROM downloads t2
WHERE t2.url_id = t1.url_id       ' at line 1`

Comment: For a start there's no such table as `master`. Re-read the original post - the table I am selecting from and updating is called `downloads`. The field I am trying to update is `downloads.master`

Comment: just change the master to downloads . try it now i updated my answer @Andy

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   UPDATE downloads 
    SET master = 1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t1.master
        FROM downloads t1
        WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
                 FROM downloads t2
                 WHERE t2.url_id = t1.url_id            
                 ORDER BY t2.created DESC
                 LIMIT 1)
     )
```

Comment: Gives an error unfortuantely - `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM`