# Mysql UPDATE query SET from the result of another query

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

Im stuck with this..
I've made a query...

```
    SELECT ID_Rollo, ID_Rollo_Original
FROM 
    interpretes 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT ID_Rollo_Original, ID_Rollo, count(ID_Rollo) as count
        FROM rollooriginal 
        GROUP BY rollooriginal.ID_Rollo
        HAVING count = 1
    ) rollooriginal ON  interpretes.ID_Programa = rollooriginal.ID_Rollo
WHERE 
interpretes.ID_Prog IS NULL AND ID_Rollo IS NOT NULL
```

returns me something like this:

```
ID_Rollo:  ID_Rollo_Original
78 ------- 656
88 ------- 5012
```

In other hand i have a table **interpretes** with some cols.

```
ID_table: ID_Programa: ID_Prog: etc: etc:
1 ------- 78 -------- NULL ------
2 ------- 88 -------- NULL ------
3 ------- 642 ------- 2108 ------
etc....
```

In some cases ID_Prog is NULL, what i need to do is create query to UPDATE the table **interpretes** and copy the result of ID_Rollo_Original to ID_Prog if ID_Prog IS NULL..

Notice that ID_Rollo from the query and ID_Programa from **interpretes** are equals.

EXPECTED

```
ID_table: ID_rollo: ID_Prog: etc: etc:
1 ------- 78 ------ 656 ------
2 ------- 88 ------ 5012 ------
```

Something like this...

> UPDATE interpretes SET interpretes.ID_Prog = (ID_Rollo_Original) WHERE
>   interpretes.ID_Programa = (RESULT ID_Rollo) AND interpretes.ID_Prog IS
>   NULL

Comment: You can check here using temporary table:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68108553/7820853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be using a join with subquery

```
UPDATE interpretes  a 
INNER  JOIN (
    SELECT ID_Rollo, ID_Rollo_Original
    FROM interpretes 
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT ID_Rollo_Original, ID_Rollo, count(ID_Rollo) as count
            FROM rollooriginal 
            GROUP BY rollooriginal.ID_Rollo
            HAVING count = 1
        ) rollooriginal ON  interpretes.ID_Programa = rollooriginal.ID_Rollo
    WHERE interpretes.ID_Prog IS NULL AND ID_Rollo IS NOT NULL
  ) T on t.ID_ROLLO = a.ID_ROLLO 
  SET a.ID_Prog = t.ID_Rollo_Original
  WHERE a.ID_Prog is NULL
```