# Reference code at the and of all product name

Tags: mysql, prestashop

I have a table ps_product with:

ps_product

```
-------------------------
|id_product |reference  |
-------------------------
|1          |c11111     |
|2          |x222222    |
|3          |x222222    |
-------------------------
```

and a table ps_product_lang with:

ps_product_lang

```
---------------------------------
|id_product |name               |
---------------------------------
|1          |Disco 1TB          |
|2          |Disco x222222 2TB  |
|3          |Disco 3TB x3333    |
---------------------------------
```

Is there a MySQL script to run in PhPMyAdmin to add reference code at the and of all product name ?

The result should be:

ps_product_lang

```
---------------------------------
|id_product |name               |
---------------------------------
|1          |Disco 1TB c11111   |
|2          |Disco 2TB x222222  |
|3          |Disco 3TB x3333    |
---------------------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262848/3270427

Comment: Is DISCO and TB are common keywords in the entire table?

Comment: No, it's an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` pl
LEFT JOIN `ps_product` p
    ON p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
SET pl.`name` = REPLACE(CONCAT(REPLACE(pl.`name`, p.`reference`, ""), " ",p.`reference`), "  ", " ");
```

First we check if the reference exists inside the old name and remove it

```
REPLACE(pl.`name`, p.`reference`, "")
```

Then we add the reference at the end with a space

```
CONCAT(REPLACE(pl.`name`, p.`reference`, ""), " ",p.`reference`)
```

Finally we remove unwanted double spaces due to the removing of the reference in the old name field.

```
REPLACE(CONCAT(REPLACE(pl.`name`, p.`reference`, ""), " ",p.`reference`), "  ", " ")
```

Comment: I get the message:
/* Errore SQL (1406): Data too long for column 'name' at row 1 */

Comment: The message is explicit, some references and names are too long to be concatenated together, due to the limit of 256 characters on the name field.

Comment: I have solved by modifying my.ini
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Answer (score 0):

I think this way is more natural:

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang pl, ps_product p SET pl.name = CONCAT(RTRIM(REPLACE(pl.name, p.reference, '')), ' ', p.reference) WHERE p.id_product = pl.id_product
```

Comment: it does not check if the reference code is already included in the name