# MySQL - copy data from row to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-workbench, mysql-backup

I have a table1 and table2 
I want to update the address in table2 according to the name in table1

for example :

table 1 (the curent update data)

jhonny 1st street
david 2nd street
danny 4th street

table 2 (old):

jhonny unknown

david 5th street

danny france

daniel 2nd street

table2 (need to be as  table1)

jhonny 1st street

david 2nd street

danny 4th street

daniel 2nd street

is there a command that do it automateclly ? 
or I need to write a code for it?

Thanks ,

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Table1, Table2
SET Table2.address = Table1.address
WHERE Table1.Name = Table2.Name
```