# What's wrong with that query?

Tags: mysql

When I run this query I got syntax error.
Why?

```
UPDATE `p` SET `p`.`PIVA` = `i`.`CCT_CODICE_PI`, `p`.`CODICE_FISCALE` = `i`.`CCT_CF`
FROM `CONTATTI_T_Contab_Progetti_Finale` `p`
LEFT JOIN `CONTATTI_T_Contab_Anagrafica` `i` ON `p`.`CCK_ANAGRAFICA` = `i`.`CCK_ANAGRAFICA`
WHERE `p`.`DAK_ANES_COGE` < 2014
```

Comment: set comes after from/joins an before where.

Comment: what _exactly_ does the syntax error say? It should be giving you a clue about roughly where the problem lies.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM 'CONTATTI_T_Contab_Progetti_Finale' 'p' LEFT JOIN 'CONTATTI_T_Contab_Anagr' at line 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - update syntax is different for MYSql

```
UPDATE `CONTATTI_T_Contab_Progetti_Finale` `p`
LEFT JOIN `CONTATTI_T_Contab_Anagrafica` `i` ON `p`.`CCK_ANAGRAFICA` = `i`.`CCK_ANAGRAFICA`
SET `p`.`PIVA` = `i`.`CCT_CODICE_PI`, `p`.`CODICE_FISCALE` = `i`.`CCT_CF`
WHERE `p`.`DAK_ANES_COGE` < 2014
```