# Is it possible in mysql-Server to write a statement which updates as select Statement

Tags: mysql, select, updates

For example:

```
Update 
select( 
a.MssstID,
a.ProbenNahmenStellenBezeichnung as Bezeichnung,
a.ProbenNahmenStellenOKZ as OKZ,
a.ProbenNahmenStellenTyp as Typ,
a.ZeitVon,
a.ZeitBis,
a.ServiceZeit,
a.Bemerkung as Messtellenbemerkung,
b.Bemerkungen as Objektbemerkung,
b.Objektbezeichnung
from messstellen as a,messstellenobjekte as b  
where a.MsstObjId=b.MsstObjId 
and a.KdNr=b.KdNr
and a.MssstID=2123) as a
set a.Bezeichnung="XXXX"
```

This Statement apperantly does not work.
Is there any mistake or are such statements not possible.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query)