# Move one column from one table to another mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, *Products* and *Images*. The Products table has an "image" column, I want to move the images inside said column to the *Images* table. The *Images* table has column "product_id", that's how both tables are related

**Products table**

```
id
image
```

**Images Table**

```
id
image
product_id
```

The ID from the *Products* table should work as a foreign key in the *Images* table under product_id for image, it should works the same as a primary key in *Products* table as for images. One more thing, *Images* Table is not empty it already has data in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query)

Comment: Are you asking us for a query that will move the contents of `Product.image` to `Images.image`

Comment: I assume there are no rows yet in the Images table... right?

Comment: yes @RiggsFolly and no images table already has data under both product_id and image column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO` with raw data, but you can also combine it with a `SELECT` query.

For the new `Id` values on your `Images` table, you can use the existing `Product.Id` values or generate new ones with a function like `UUID()`, which I would recommend because it makes longer more unique IDs that can be globally unique.

Something like this will probably work:

```sql
INSERT INTO Images (id, image, product_id)
SELECT UUID(), image, id FROM Products;
```

Comment: ok i get it. thank you... now i should simply drop the image table from products