# How to change the picker items font size in Xamarin IOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

In Xamarin forms, for IOS if the picker item has lengthy text, that text is getting truncated. How to change the xamarin ios picker items font size using customrenderer or how to make the text fit without getting truncated?.

Answer (score 1):

There is another alternative solution as well where you can change the alignment of Picker Item(Default is Center). You can make it left.

For adjusting Text and Style there are plenty of renderer solutions on Stack Overlfow.

For your ref, attaching one of those solutions.
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078371/apply-styles-on-picker-items-in-xamarin-forms).