# Xamarin.Forms I want comboBox like a windows forms combobox

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Im looking for better picker because Xamarin.Forms picker is really bad and I dont want like that, Is there any custom picker or something like comboBox?

[i want Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OBlp.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Xamarin.Forms.ComboBox`. Install it from `Manage NuGet Packages`.

Xaml:

```
  <combobox:ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" 
                           ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}"                                   
                           SelectedItemChanged="ComboBox_SelectedItemChanged"                                
                           Visual="Material">
            <combobox:ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" Padding="5,5,0,0"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </combobox:ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </combobox:ComboBox>
```

Code:

```
public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
{
    public Page3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext=new Page3ViewModel();
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox.Text = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }       
}

public class Page3ViewModel
{
    public List<string> ItemsSource { get; set; }   
    public Page3ViewModel()
    {
        ItemsSource = new List<string>()
        {
            "Item1",
            "Item2",
            "Item3",
            "Item4"
        };

    }
  }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Think it's not possible but you could create your custom picker dialog design following this post [Apply styles on Picker items in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078371/apply-styles-on-picker-items-in-xamarin-forms).

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous answer, you could also use [SyncFusion Xamarin ComboBox](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/combobox/getting-started), tho it might need a license (not sure)

The Website contains information about it as well as code samples and examples on how to set it up, also have other "Types" of ComboBox.

Comment: The pricing can be found here https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/products

Comment: do you NEED a license tho? I've been using said libraries without purchasing anything, it just sends a pop-up at the beginning of the program

Comment: The trial license is temporary. The Community License provides free access to Syncfusion Essential Studio products for companies and individuals with less than $1 million USD in annual gross revenue and 5 or fewer developers.