# How can I create an spinning picker in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, picker

I am trying to get my picker to be an wheel/spinning type.

[image]

My Current Picker:

```
<Picker x:Name="AmountPicker" />
```

```
AmountPicker.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8" };
```

[My Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JCH4.jpg)

Comment: What research have you done? search `xamarin spinning picker` - I see lots of hits.

Comment: Just create a simple empty Custom Renderer for Picker in Android and by default you will get that spinning picker

Comment: In my option, by a long way the easiest answer is to use one of [Syncfusion's controls](https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

**1.** Use [Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) which enables you to achieve the `wheel/spinning` type. There is a similar thread you could refer to: [Apply styles on Picker items in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078371/apply-styles-on-picker-items-in-xamarin-forms).

1.1 Create the Custom Picker Control in Shared Project:

```
    public class MyPicker : Picker
    {
    }
```

1.2 Creating the Custom Renderer on **Android** & **iOS**:

**Android:**

```
using Xamarin.Forms; 
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPicker), typeof(MyPickerRenderer))]
namespace App35.Droid
{
    class MyPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {

        public MyPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**iOS:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPicker), typeof(MyPickerRenderer))]
namespace App35.iOS
{
    class MyPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

1.3 Consume it in XAML:

```
   <local:MyPicker ItemsSource="{Binding MyListProperty}" ></local:MyPicker>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**2.** Use [Xamarin.SfPicker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPicker). Firstly, install the [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPicker) and then set SfPicker control namespace as `xmlns:syncfusion="clr- namespace:Syncfusion.SfPicker.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfPicker.XForms` in XAML Content page. So you can consume it in XAML like below.For more you can refer to [Getting Started with Xamarin Picker (SfPicker)](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/picker/gettingstarted?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=xaml)

```
   <syncfusion:SfPicker x:Name="picker" HeaderText="Choose Value" />
```

**3.** Use [Wheel Picker for Xamarin Samples](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vapolia.WheelPicker.Forms/) package, you can refer to [Wheel Picker for Xamarin Samples](https://vapolia.eu/product/wheelpicker) for more details.

Comment: First option has limitation that only 3 items are visible.