# How to insert values into a column in table B based on values in table A

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and only know basic commands right now. I'm trying to get a value for a column 'position' in table 'role' based on the value of column 'salary' in table 'payroll'.

Table 'role' and 'payroll' contain three common columns 'employee_ID', 'first_name' and 'last_name' with common values. I want to use another column 'salary' in table 'payroll' to determine the output for column 'position' in table 'role'.

For example, if the 'salary' column in table 'payroll' has a value less than 2000, I want the 'position' column in table 'role' to display 'janitor'.

This is what I'm using.

```
update role 
set position = 'janitor' 
where (select salary from payroll) > 2000
```

And this is the error I'm getting.

#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Could you please clarify how tables role and payroll are related to each other?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You need to define the `JOIN` criteria which tells the database engine how to associate each `position` row with each `payroll` row. Even if you have an FK relationship defined, SQL does not use those to infer a _natural join_ - you always need to be explicit.

Comment: Table 'role' and 'payroll' contain three common columns 'employee_ID', 'first_name' and 'last_name' with common values. I want to use another column 'salary' in table 'payroll' to determine the output for column 'position' in table 'role'

Comment: Not sure, if this syntax is supported by MySQL     UPDATE R SET R.POSITION='JANITOR' FROM ROLE AS R JOIN PAYROLL AS P ON R.EMPLOYEE_ID=P.EMPLOYEE_ID AND R.FIRST_NAME=P.FIRST_NAME AND R.LAST_NAME=P.LAST_NAME WHERE P.SALARY>2000

Comment: I tried it but got an error. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM ROLE AS R JOIN PAYROLL AS P ON R.EMPLOYEE_ID=P.EMPLOYEE_ID AND R.FIRST_NAME' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL doesn't use a `FROM` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query) when doing an `UPDATE` from a query.

[The MySQL syntax is this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) (parts in square-brackets are optional, parts in angle-brackets are placeholders):

```
UPDATE <table_references>
SET <assignment_list>
[WHERE <where_condition>]

-- <table_references> is defined as:
tableName1 [ AS <alias1> ] [ <join_operator> tableName2 [ AS <alias2> ] ON <join_criteria> ] [...]
```

So try this:

```
UPDATE
    role AS r
    INNER JOIN payroll AS p ON p.employee_id = r.employee_id
SET
    position = 'janitor'
WHERE
    p.salary > 2000
```

Another approach is to use a temporary-table with a `WHERE IN` predicate:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE employeeIds ( employeeId int NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO employeeIds ( employeeId )
SELECT employee_id FROM payroll WHERE salary > 2000;

UPDATE
    role
SET
    position = 'janitor'
WHERE
    employee_id IN ( SELECT employee_id FROM employeeIds );
```

The temporary table `employeeIds` will be deleted when you disconnect from the database - I assume you're using MySQL Workbench or similar. I don't know what the connection lifetime semantics are when using a web-based tool like phpMyAdmin, however.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked perfectly. I then used it to calculate the average salary of all positions titled x. select avg(salary) from payroll as p INNER JOIN role AS r ON r.employee_id = p.employee_id WHERE r.position = 'data_analyst'