# Copy row from same table in mysql but alter certain columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with copying a row from the same table and editing certain columns to create a new row.

Example Table (yes I know there is not a primary key):

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    columnToNotChange JSON, -- this column does not change
    columnToNotChangeTwo VARCHAR(5), -- this column does not change either
    columnToChange BOOLEAN -- this column I want to change 
);
```

Say I have a row:

```
columnToNotChange = '{json_object: []}'
columnToNotChangeTwo = "const"
columnToChange = true
```

What I want to know is how do you copy the data from the columnToNotChange and ColumnToNotChangeTwo but alter the columnToChange to create a new row in the table, myTable.

I've heard of UPDATE FROM (SELECT) statements but haven't found any good documentation for MySQL on UPDATE FROM (SELECT) statements.

I have looked [Generic Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query), [MySQL Documentation on The UPDATE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html), and [W3Schools SQL UPDATE Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

I appreciate any help.

Comment: This looks useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371315/2310830

Comment: Simple `INSERT NewTable (Col1, COl2, Col3) SELECT old.Col1, old.Col2, Calculation FROM old`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you want copy a rows  with pk id = 1

you should use an INSERT SELECT
if you want a new row and null values all the columns except  columnToNotChange , columnToNotChangeTwo

then

```
insert into myTable  ( columnToNotChange , columnToNotChangeTwo  )
select columnToNotChange , columnToNotChangeTwo 
from myTable  
where id = 1
```

if you want assign some value to the column columnToChange
then assign at the 3th column then value you need

```
insert into myTable  ( columnToNotChange , columnToNotChangeTwo ,columnToChange   )
select columnToNotChange , columnToNotChangeTwo, 'THE VALUE YOU WANT FOR columnToChange'
from myTable  
where id = 1
```