# I have to loop through 9600 DISTINCT Domains in query 1 and Update an id in a second table in Query 2

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

The query takes forever to update all Domains in the second table.

Maybe there is a more efficient way to approach this?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","xxx");

if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
  exit();
}

// Perform queries
$result = $mysqli->query(SELECT DISTINCT dom FROM pmcts_mt_pipeline_details);

$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
$dom = $row['dom'];
$mysqli->query("UPDATE pmcts_email_marketing_companies_pharma_all_unique SET id_ind_mailer=1 WHERE email_dom='$dom' AND (mailerdaemon=0 AND mail_excluded=0 AND unsubscribe=0 AND changeto=0)");
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why do you need to read all columns and run a seperate `UPDATE` query? Why not do all that directly with one query?

Comment: It seems that an [UPDATE from SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query) should solve your problem.

Comment: I even loop to 40.000 Domains, Brilliant!

Comment: @NicoHaase: I Used the tip from Martijn. I Only used the suggestion with a small modification. Not using the foreach Loop which was the cause for slowing it down drasticly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely not the query that's slow, but the loop. Looping in PHP is slow.

You want to update one value to all matching rows, you might be able to use [IN()](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx):

```
$result = $mysqli->query(SELECT DISTINCT dom FROM pmcts_mt_pipeline_details);
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$doms = array_column($rows, 'dom'); // *
$domsString = implode("','", $doms)
```

<sup>** Im not 100% about the array column, but the goals is to get all values-only in an array*</sup>

```
UPDATE pmcts_email_marketing_companies_pharma_all_unique 
SET id_ind_mailer=1 
WHERE email_dom IN ('".$domsString."') 
   AND (
      mailerdaemon=0 
      AND mail_excluded=0 
      AND unsubscribe=0
      AND changeto=0
   )
```

**Note:** Im assuming you are in control of the $dom-values and that they're clean and safe for mysql. If they're able to be manipulated by user input, please make sure you sanatize, or even better: use prepared statements.

Comment: I hope that none of the `dom` values contains a quote....

Comment: Been working with proper frameworks for a while, manual sanatision slips my mind sometimes. I've added it to my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot Martjin, very useful. The only thing I had to change is:
```
$doms = array_column($rows, 'dom'); Then it worked fine and fast.
```

Comment: The dom values are save